# How to split a dataframe column by the first instance of a character in its values

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe (or vector?)

```
x <- data.frame(a=c("A_B_D", "B_C"))
```

I want to split the vector  in `x$a` into two new columns by the first instance of "_" to get

```
x$b 
[1] "A" "B_D"
```

and

```
x$c
[2] "B" "C"
```

i tried variants of gsub, but couldnt come to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option might be to use `tidyr::separate`:

```
separate(x,a,into = c("b","c"),sep = "_",remove = FALSE,extra = "merge")
```

Answer (score 3):

One idea is to replace the first `_` with another delimiter and split on the new delimiter. This works because using `sub` will only replace the first found delimiter (whereas `gsub` replaces all), i.e.

```
strsplit(sub('_', ',', x$a), ',', fixed = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "A"   "B_D"

#[[2]]
#[1] "B" "C"
```

To create two new columns in your original data frame,

```
within(x, new <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(sub('_', ',', x$a), ',', fixed = TRUE))))
#      a new.X1 new.X2
#1 A_B_D      A    B_D
#2   B_C      B      C
```

Comment: It's a clever solution!

Comment: Nice! How to split into x$b and x$c? Maybe i should be more clear.