# split columns in a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames which some columns have this special character **->**(arrow). Now i do want to loop through this list of data frames and locate columns with  this **->** (arrow) then the new columns be named with a suffix _old and _new. This is a sample of data frames :

```
dput(df1)
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("reg->joy", "ress", "mer->dls"),
                      t2 = c("James","Jane", "Egg")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))

dput(df2)
df2 <- structure(list(v1 = c("me", "df", "kl"),
                      t2 = c("James","Jane->dlt", "Egg"),
                      t3 = c("James ->may","Jane", "Egg")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
dput(df3)
df3 <- structure(list(v1 = c("56->34", "df23-> ", "mkl"),
                      t2 = c("James","Jane", "Egg"),
                      d3 = c("James->","Jane", "Egg")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

This is what I have tried

```
dfs <- list(df1,df2,df3)

for (y in 1:length(dfs)){
  setDT(dfs[[y]])
  df1<- lapply(names(dfs[[y]]), function(x) {
    mDT <- df2[[y]][, tstrsplit(get(x), " *-> *")]
    if (ncol(mDT) == 2L) setnames(mDT, paste0(x, c("_old", "_new")))
  }) %>% as.data.table()

}
```

This only splits one data frame, I need to split all of the data frames

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
dput(df1)
df1 <- structure(list(v1_old = c("reg", "mer"),
                      v1_new = c("joy", "dls")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))

dput(df2)
df2 <- structure(list(t2_old = c("dlt"),
                      t2_new = c("dlt"),
                      t3_old = c("James"),
                      t3_new = c("may")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))

dput(df3)
df3 <- structure(list(v1_old = c("56", "df23 "),
                      v1_new = c("34", " "),
                      d3 = c("James"),
                      d3 = c(" ")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

Comment: @jay.sf Yes I have added expected output

Comment: Step 1: how to split column by character https://stackoverflow.com/a/55748969/6086135 Step 2: apply function on list of dfs... pick from here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+function+on+list+of+dataframes

Comment: @Bernd Konfuzius This is not helping at all

Comment: You have a list of dataframes (df). In every df, you would like to split a column into two, using the string `->`. Is that not your question?

Comment: @ Bernd Konfuzius The code I have shared already performs the splitting, only that it works with one data frame, What I want is how to implement the code on a list of data frames

Comment: I am not sure why you would insist on using your implementation, when there is functions available for which it is straight forward to iterate over a list of dfs. But I agree, in that case my answer is not helping at all.

Answer (score 0):

So I have played around and found the answer

```
df1 <-c()
for (y in 1:length(dfs)){
  setDT(dfs[[y]])
  df1[[y]] <- lapply(names(modifiedtbl[[y]]), function(x) {
    mDT <- dfs[[y]][, tstrsplit(get(x), " *-> *")]
    if (ncol(mDT) == 2L) setnames(mDT, paste0(x, c("_old", "_new")))
  }) %>% as.data.table()

}
```